# Can pods be deployed on k3s nodes with roles control-plane,etcd,master

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, k3sup

I have followed this tutorial https://vmguru.com/2021/04/how-to-install-rancher-on-k3s/

At the end of it I end up with a running k3s cluster with 3 nodes

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                       AGE     VERSION
master1   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   7d20h   v1.23.5+k3s1
master2   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   7d20h   v1.23.5+k3s1
master3   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   7d20h   v1.23.5+k3s1
```

The cluster is using embeded etcd datastore

I am confused because I am able to deploy to workloads to this cluster. I thought I could only deploy workload to nodes with a role of `Worker`?

In other tutorials, the end result is master and worker roles on different nodes, so I am not even sure how I managed to get this combination of roles. Has something changed in the k3s distribution perhaps. The author used 1.19 I am using 1.23?

Answer (score 0):

A node role is just a label. There are no specs that define what must happen if you use a label like `role=control-plane`.

While there are some well-known labels, among which you can find [node role=control-plane](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#node-role-kubernetes-io-control-plane), Kubernetes distributions (like k3s) don't have to follow these conventions.

`kube-scheduler` actually uses Taints and Tolerations do prevent workloads running on specific nodes. To see if a node has taints run `kubectl describe node <node_name>` and look for the taints field. If there are none, all workloads will run on them.

For single node clusters it's a necessary requirement that control plane components and normal workloads can run on the same machine. Even more so, putting cluster workloads on a different machine is *just a best practice*. Kubernetes distributions like k3s or microk8s were specifically build for smaller node clusters and [disable taints by default.](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1279)